# What's good about I-projections?

Tags: estimation, kullback-leibler

There seems to be a large body of applied research where distribution q is picked to minimize [KL(q,p)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) where p is empirical distribution. Are there theoretical reasons to prefer this estimator? For instance, a theoretical reason to prefer MLE for estimating mean of a one-dimensional Gaussian with mean between -1 and 1 because it's admissible, and also as sample size goes to infinity, it minimizes maximum risk and Bayes risk.

Comment: Is the KL minimization you refer to is done while containing p? (Otherwise, the minimizer will be trivially q). If so- KL minimization can be seen as an orthogonal projection, under KL norm.

Comment: @JohnRos - I think your comment is a good start for an answer here.  Do you want to repost as an answer and perhaps expand on the meaning/significance of "orthogonal projection under KL norm"?  Yaroslav, I notice you are still an active user - could you indicate if this goes someway to answer your question or not?  Thanks

Comment: This needs more background or context, what is $q$? If $q \in Q$, where $Q$ is a family of distributions indexed by $\theta$ you can show some connection to maximum likelihood. If $Q$ can be any imaginable density, we will just wind up with the EDF every single time which isn't interesting.